# About $−\vert x \vert\le x \le \vert x \vert$ in absolute values

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

So, i'm really strugling with this one, when studying the triangle inequality, the inequality  $−|x|≤x≤|x|$ pops really often, however I just can't get why this is true.  I've seen only two different approaches, one that it seems to me too trivial:

Since:

$|x|≤a⇔−a≤x≤a$

We can write:

$|x|≤|x|$

as

$−|x|≤x≤|x|$

Is that reasoning even valid?

And the other way, very informal, is that because $x=|x|$  or $x=−|x|$  depending on the sign of $x$ then the inequality is satisfied.

Why does the distance $x$ has the possibility to be greater than $x$ itself, shouldn't it only be that $x=|x|$ in any case? why greater than?

I just don't get it, and if I substitute in the inequality for $x>0$ and $x<0$ I don't have any idea what to do with it:

For $x<0$:

$ −(−x)≤x≤−x$

that is

$x≤x≤−x$

For $x>0$:

$x≤x≤x$

I know this should be really easy to grasp, but I just can't really REALLY understand how to use that inequality.

Answer (score 5):

- If $x = 0$ then it's obvious that $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$ because $$-|x| = x = |x| = 0.$$
- If $x > 0$ then $x = |x|$ and
  $$ -\underbrace{x}_{=|x|} < 0 < x =|x|.$$
  Therefore $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|.$
- If $x < 0$ then $x = -|x|$ and
  $$  -|x| = x< 0 < -\underbrace{x}_{-|x|} = |x|.$$
  Therefore $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|.$

> Why does the distance $x$ has the possibility to be greater than $x$ itself, shouldn't it only be that $x=|x|$ in any case? why greater than?

If $x = y$ than it is also true that $x \leq y$. The latter statement is less precise than the former, sure, but it is a true statement.

At least one of these inequalities 
$$-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$$
is actually an equality. Which one of them ? Well it depends on the nature of $x$ (positive, negative, zero). Therefore it's better to put inequalities because it is true for all $x$.

> I've seen only two different approaches, one that it seems to me too trivial [...] Is that reasoning even valid?

Yes, it is.

Comment: well, it amazes me how something so trivial can be actually valid, also now i get it why you should put the greater than sign, this was very enlightening , you have no idea how frustrated I was with this small thing, so i really apreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The value of $x$ must be either $-|x|$ or $|x|$ depending on the sign of $x$. This can be expressed as the inequality you listed $-|x|\leq x\leq|x|$. I think you are trying to compare it to an inequality like $0\leq x\leq4$ where $x$ could take any value from $0$ to $4$. In your situation this is not the case, $x$ can only be one of two specific values, namely $-|x|$ or $|x|$.

> Why does the distance $x$ has the possibility to be greater than $x$ itself, shouldn't it only be that $x=|x|$ in any case? why greater than?

The distance $|x|$ will always be a non-negative number where as $x$ can be a negative number so in some cases (i.e. $x<0$) we have that the distance is greater than the value (where greater is meaning signed magnitude not just magnitude).

Comment: > "...where xx could take any value from 00 to 44"


Yes!! I was actually thinking like that and causing me more confusion than it should. 

Thanks for your help, you really helped me out to understand also the stuff about the distance being greater than $x$. Reaaaally thaaaaanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Inequalities are used in a variety of ways and we always have to check we are thinking of all possible ways.